# MySQL Batch increase value?

Tags: sql, mysql

My client has asked me if I can update about 500 of his prices (increase by 10.00).

The products are all stored in a MySQL table, can anyone give me an example SQL query that will do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is an example that will update all the prices for CategoryID 27:

```
update MyTable
set Price = Price + 10
where CategoryID = 27
```

Before you run an [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) query like this, make sure you are going to update the right records by running a [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) query with the same `WHERE` clause and examining the results:

```
select *
from MyTable
where CategoryID = 27
```

**Note**

The above assumes there is no price history being maintained. You will have to examine the table structure to know whether this is the case or not. If price history is being maintained, you will need to take a different approach, depending upon how the schema is structured. IF you let us know what your schema is, we can be more specific.